# Scraping Facebook Messages from html files with rvest

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

As it is possible to download a copy of your Facebook data archive, and it provides html files of every individual chat you have. I would like to be able to get that into a dataframe for further analysis.

An example of one of the files looks like this:
[image]

and I have uploaded an example of that html file here: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/eldenvo/182efcd870f74d715b202f3ccdae335e/raw/1b53610459790489efb43ab6caa0f15103d391a1/facebook-message.html

My ideal would be to get the data into a dataframe with the columns: sender, message, time.

So using

```
library(rvest)

doc <- "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/eldenvo/182efcd870f74d715b202f3ccdae335e/raw/1b53610459790489efb43ab6caa0f15103d391a1/facebook-message.html"
doc %>% read_html()
```

returns

```
#> {xml_document}
#> <html>
#> [1] <head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n<base href="../">\n<style type="text/c ...
#> [2] <body>\n<a href="html/messages.htm">Back</a><br><br><div class="thread">Conversation with p1, p2<div class="message ..
```

And using the selector tool in Chrome to try and extract something more:

```
doc %>% read_html() %>% html_node(xpath = '/html/body/div/div[1]')
#> {xml_node}
#> <div class="message">
#> [1] <div class="message_header">\n<span class="user">p1</span><span class="meta">Monday, 19 March 2012 at 23:29 UTC</sp ...
```

or

```
doc %>% read_html() %>% html_node(xpath = '/html/body/div/p/text()') %>% html_text()

#> [1] "I didn't see your message before, i'm sorry that i didn't answer. Next time i promise !!"
```

I'm not very familiar with `html` or `rvest` so I'm not sure about the best way to extract the full list of messages and associated info into a `data.frame`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article could help you a lot: https://blog.rstudio.com/2014/11/24/rvest-easy-web-scraping-with-r/

Especially the hint for http://selectorgadget.com, which makes it a lot easier to find appropriate tags to extract.

Your current example would work like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

doc <-  "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/eldenvo/182efcd870f74d715b202f3ccdae335e/raw/1b53610459790489efb43ab6caa0f15103d391a1/facebook-message.html"

pg <- doc %>% read_html()
```

We create a little helper to re-use a few times:

```r
extract_nodes <- function(pg, css) {
  pg %>%
    html_nodes(css) %>%
    html_text()
}
```

Next, we extract the relevant part about the date. After that, we need to process and parse the date. I remove the beginning of the string "Monday, ....", afterwards it is just a matter of setting the correct parameters for `parse_datetime`, which can be found in the help-file.

```r
dates <- pg %>%
  extract_nodes("span[class='meta']") %>%
  str_replace("^.*,\\s", "") %>%
  parse_datetime(format = "%d %B %Y %* %H:%M %*")
```

Once the dates are settled, we can easily parse messages and users:

```r
result <- data_frame(
  user = extract_nodes(pg, "span[class='user']"),
  dates = dates,
  message = extract_nodes(pg, "p")

)
result
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>    user               dates
#>   <chr>              <dttm>
#> 1    p1 2012-03-19 23:29:00
#> 2    p2 2012-03-19 15:39:00
#> 3    p1 2012-03-19 08:34:00
#> 4    p1 2012-03-18 20:24:00
#> # ... with 1 more variables: message <chr>
```